# unexpected behaviors on classes when testing with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm working on some tests on my project, and have run in to some weird behaviors.

My code looks something like this:

```
export class Variable {
  b;

  constructor() {
    this.b = 'B';
  }

  changeValue = () => {
    this.b = 'changed B';
  };
}

export class DerivedVariable {
  v;

  constructor(v: Variable[]) {
    this.v = v;
  }
}

export class Store {
  a;

  v;

  initialize = () => {
    this.a = new Variable();
  };

  get computedValue() {
    return [this.a];
  }

  get computedInstances() {
    return new DerivedVariable(this.computedValue);
  }
}
```

and my test code:

```
test('test', () => {
    const { a, computedValue, computedInstances, initialize } = new Store();

    initialize();

    expect(computedValue[0].b).toBe('B');

    computedValue[0].changeValue();

    expect(a.b).toBe('changed B');

    expect(computedInstances.v[0].b).toBe('changed B');
  });
```

I figured running the `initialize` function would populate the class variable, which would allow the test to pass.

However, the results of the test returns something like:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b')

      24 |     initialize();
      25 |
    > 26 |     expect(computedValue[0].b).toBe('B');
```

Does jest have an asynchronous behavior when it comes to creating class instances?

Thanks in advance.

- On a side note, I've run into a similar issue when testing with class variables after calling a function that mutates it, I assume the two issues are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, I can't believe I missed something so obvious,

but I was able to figure out what was wrong with some process of elimination and research.

I ran into a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049246/destructured-variable-value-not-persisting-between-modules) which led me to the right direction.

Apparently there were no problems at all regarding arrow functions, lexical scopes and whatnot,

I had just forgotten about how object assignment in javascript works.

Reassigning the variable `a` would populate the variable with a memory address to another value,

and the destructured `a` in the test code would point to the "old" object

In code:

```
test('test', () => {
    const { a, computedValue, computedInstances, initialize } = new Store();
    // the variable a points to the initial value, which would be undefined

    initialize(); 
    // at this point, a is assigned a newly created Variable, which would make the destructured "a" obsolete at this point
  });
```